# ggplot2 manually adjust linetype of main plot but remove outline of geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem in removing the outline of the confidence interval of geom_ribbon. Below is the code for a simplified version of the graph I would like to make:

```
Values <- 1:20 + rnorm(20,20,sd=3);
dat <- data.frame(Group= rep(c("G1", "G2"), each=10),
    Xvals <- 1:20,
    Yvals = Values,
    CIL = (Values -2),
    CIH = (Values +2))

ad <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Xvals,y=Yvals,colour=Group)) +
geom_line(aes(linetype=Group)) +
scale_colour_manual(values=c("G1"="#FF6600","G2"="#0000FF")) +  
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("G1"="solid", "G2"="dotdash" )) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=CIL,ymax=CIH,linetype=Group),alpha=0.1) 
ad
```

[image]

I want to remove the outline of the confidence interval (just keep the shaded area)  but keep the manually adjusted color and linetype of the main lines (Yvals). Right now using geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=CIL,ymax=CIH,linetype=NA) - which would normally remove the outline - is not working since the linetype is already specified. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So maybe keep the `linetype` (or add `group`) but get rid of the `colour` via `colour = NA` in `geom_ribbon`?

Comment: Remove the color aesthetic from the call to `ggplot` and put it inside `geom_line`. That will give you the line colors for `geom_line`, but remove the lines completely from `geom_ribbon`. I'd also suggest reversing the order of `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` so that the lines will be drawn on top of the confidence bands.

Comment: You could also add (1) `fill=Group` to `geom_ribbon` so that the confidence bands will also be colored and (2) `theme_bw()` which will give a white background that will make your lines and confidence bands show up better. And since you already have `Group` mapped to colour, you don't really need `linetype` in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried option `lty=0` to change the line type in `geom_ribbon`? Like

```
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=CIL,ymax=CIH,linetype=Group), alpha=0.1, lty=0)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate your thinking here? With more explanation this answer would be stronger. As-is it reads like a comment, although your suggestion seems to provide the desired solution.